# How can I use Gulp to build all projects under a specific folder within my ASP.NET MVC solution?

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, gulp, gulp-task

I have MVC solution with below structure

```
MainSolution
    FeatureFolder
        Project1
        Project2
                Project3
    FoundationFolder
        Project4
        Project5
```

I want to build all the projects under Feature Folder by using Gulp Task

Please help to do this

Answer (score 0):

Considering you already have a `gulpfile.js`, the following should work, although not tested.

```
const gulp = require('gulp');
const { spawn } = require('child_process');

// Task to build a project
function buildProject(projectPath) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const buildProcess = spawn('dotnet', ['build', projectPath]);

    buildProcess.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
      console.log(data.toString());
    });

    buildProcess.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
      console.error(data.toString());
    });

    buildProcess.on('close', (code) => {
      if (code === 0) {
        resolve();
      } else {
        reject(new Error(`Build process exited with code ${code}`));
      }
    });
  });
}

// Task to build all projects under the Feature folder
gulp.task('build-feature-projects', async function () {
  try {
    await buildProject('./FeatureFolder/Project1');
    await buildProject('./FeatureFolder/Project2');
    await buildProject('./FeatureFolder/Project2/Project3');
    console.log('All feature projects built successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error building feature projects:', error);
  }
});

// Default task
gulp.task('default', gulp.series('build-feature-projects'));
```

If you want to build all projects inside the folder you can do the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

// Task to build all projects under the Feature folder
gulp.task('build-feature-projects', async function () {
  try {
    const featureFolder = './FeatureFolder';
    const projects = fs.readdirSync(featureFolder)
      .map(fileName => path.join(featureFolder, fileName))
      .filter(file => fs.statSync(file).isDirectory());

    for (const project of projects) {
      await buildProject(project);
    }

    console.log('All feature projects built successfully.');
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error building feature projects:', error);
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks for your response. Is it possible to improve this function so that we don't need to sepecidy each project list. function need to take all the projects under that folder. in visual studio it ispossible to build all the projects under a folder by right clicking on folder. similar to this

Comment: See my update to the answer.